# Weird bug in my program that I don't know how to explain

Tags: python, wxpython, contextmenu

I'm writing a simple clipboard manager in wxpython for fun and profit and I've run across a peculiar bug that is causing the same function to be called no matter which menu item is clicked.

The code is [here](https://gist.github.com/1699128) and problem is related to lines 49-56 (the "Clear" item works just fine) - it always calls the last function created.

I tried printing the lambda function being created, the menu item, it's ID - pretty much everything that I could think of that could have been the source of problem, but I didn't find any clues.

I'm kinda stuck if I can't choose menu items so I'd appreciate all and any help.

Comment: Do you mean to say `func = lambda e: self.ChooseItem(item_id)` rather than `i`?

Comment: @snim2 No, because item_id is the ID the menu item widget gets, i is the ID of item in history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `i` is being looked-up in the enclosing scope of `CreateHistoryMenu`. When the `func` is called, `i` equals the last value in the loop. That is why the menu items all call the last function created.

If you add `i` to the arguments of the `lambda` with a default value, `i` will become a local variable in the `lambda` itself, with a default value which was bound at the time the lambda was defined. This will be the right value for `i`:

```
        func = lambda e, i = i: self.ChooseItem(i)
```